# Get the ID of a form posted to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I've created an HttpHandler and I'm posting data to it. I'd like to get the form ID when it is posted but cannot figure out how to get that. I don't see any field in the HttpRequest that will give me this information. Is it possible to get the posted form ID from the HttpRequest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get this. You could include this information in a `hidden` form field.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me. I was thinking about using a hidden field if getting the form ID was not possible. Now on second thought it doesn't seem all that bad to use the hidden field.

Comment: Its much more logical to have it in a `hidden` form field.

Answer (score 1):

The ID attribute is not submitted; its purely for client side processing.  The forms Name is available.  If you need it, you'll have to include in in another form element.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID from the form you were looking at is in the query string then you can use `Request.UrlReferrer`